# I am trying to parse a text file delimited by commas in C#

Tags: c#

Hi I am learning how to parse text files that are delimited by commas, tabs and/or \

the text looks like this:

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",,5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```

And my code looks like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace T_2050_ParserEduardo
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
        //1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00

        Console.WriteLine("Paser con Comas");

        /*
         * Pasos
         * Crear List<clsDetalle>
         * Leer archivo en una secuencia de lines con File.ReadAllLines()
         * Para cada linea, hacer el split correspondiente
         * Manualmente convertir los valores
         */

        List<clsCarro> resp = new List<clsCarro>();
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines("d:\\ztemp\\parserExEdu.txt");
        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Count(); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                var campos = lines[i].Split(',');
                clsCarro nR = new clsCarro();
                nR.Anio = Convert.ToInt32(campos[1]);
                nR.Fabricante = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[2])) ? "" : 
                campos[2];
                nR.Modelo = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[3])) ? "" : 
                campos[3];
                nR.Descripcion = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[4])) ? "" : 
                campos[4];
                nR.Precio =  Convert.ToDouble(campos[5]);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("error en la fila {0}: {1}", i, 
                ex.Message);
                continue;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Parser terminado, tenemos {0} filas", resp.Count);
        Console.ReadLine();

      }
    }

   class clsCarro
   {
    public int Anio { get; set; }
    public string Fabricante { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public double Precio { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the Result I get is the following:

[image]

I do not quite understand what have I've done wrong

---

mmathis sugestion has helped and I no longer have the string input error.... how ever I still getting no rows in return after the file has been parsed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUxxU.png)

Comment: Why not use a well tested and free off-the-shelf solution like [CsvHelper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper/)

Comment: You're trying to convert the string "Ford" to an integer: `nR.Anio = Convert.ToInt32(campos[1]);`

Comment: nR.Anio is for Year
nr.Fabricante is for Maker
nR.Modelo is for Model

Comment: In c# array/collection indexers start with the first element being at index 0. If you are coming from VB this is a change. So `campos[1]` retrieves the 2nd element in the array, not the first.

Comment: CSV is a format complicated enough, so you should parse it yourself only for educational purpose. In other cases please use a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to convert a non-numeric string ("Ford") to an `int`:

```
nR.Anio = Convert.ToInt32(campos[1]);
```

Indexing in C# starts at 0, so index 1 will be the second item in the array. Your schema indicates this is "Make". You need to change the line to

```
nR.Anio = Convert.ToInt32(campos[0]);
```

You'll probably want to adjust the other indices for the other columns as well:

```
nR.Anio = Convert.ToInt32(campos[0]);
nR.Fabricante = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[1])) ? "" : 
      campos[1];
nR.Modelo = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[2])) ? "" : 
      campos[2];
nR.Descripcion = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(campos[3])) ? "" : 
      campos[3];
nR.Precio =  Convert.ToDouble(campos[4]);
```

Comment: is the index (i) initialized correctly as i =1 , or should it be i=0 ?

Comment: i=0 corresponds to the row of headers, so you want to leave it starting at i-1

Comment: Thanks for the help, the app no longer shows the input string error... but it does not create the new rows or lines that should be parsed... The new result will be shown in the original question.

Comment: You need to add `nR` to your list.

Answer (score 0):

For such cases, the best way is to debug your application and see what is going on in your code. By going on, I mean do a step by step analysis of your loops and conversion logic. For example in your code, the first run of your loop gives the following result:

[image]

In your second run, the following result is shown on debugging:
[image]

So basically if you were able to understand the debugging process in Visual Studio, it is going to help you pinpoint your logical errors and you would be able to resolve them as per your need.

In your case, the indices that you are trying to parse are different as seen in the first two runs, hence you are getting the exceptions. You need to make your logic certain that all indices fall in the correct category for each run of your parsing process.

Comment: Understood.. I will put this into practice. Thanks , again

Comment: I found out why the app was not returning 0 rows  ... I forgot to put resp.Add(nR)